# Inverted the labels of my classifier in error and got 100% accuracy in a kaggle in-class competiton

Tags: classification, random-forest

I am relatively new to machine learning. I am part of an in-class competition on kaggle where the task is to predict churn. I trained my model (random forests 50-200 trees) on the test data and got up to 80% accuracy using a 70-30 split. However, when I predict on the unseen data, I get zero accuracy on kaggle.

For some reason, I decided to invert the labels thinking something went wrong and then I get 100% on kaggle. Can someone explain to me why my model wrongly predicts every case in the unseen data. Confidence level of each prediction is mostly >0.7 (ergo it's not a coin toss).

Comment: Getting 0% accuracy is the same as 100% accuracy with inverted binary labels. Hence your model is basically perfect. What's the question again?

Comment: @Olivier thanks for the reply. Let me clarify my question. I was wondering if cases like mine happen often and what the explanation for this is. Is there anything I can do to my model soit rightly predicts the classes without me having to invert the labels. I ask this because I might be asked to explain my solution. Thanks